# "UNAUTHENTICATED" when trying to encrypt text with Google Cloud KMS and API-KEY

Tags: curl, api-key, google-cloud-kms

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt files with Google Cloud KMS. Encrypting/decrypting with the gcloud command works perfectly. But now I need to pass this to other users who don't/should not have acces to my gcloud account. They should be able to decrypt and encrypt with the curl command.

I've tried: 
- En/Decrypting with the gcloud command. Works perfectly
- En/Decrypting on an google cloud compute engine. Works perfectly
- En/Decrypting with curl. Does not work.

```
base64 appsettings.json.encrypted -w 0 > appsettings.json.encrypted.base

curl -v "https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid/locations/global/keyRings/test/cryptoKeys/quickstart:encrypt" -d "{\"plaintext\":\"$(cat appsettings.json.encrypted.base)\"}"   -H "Authorization:Bearer API KEY"  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I expect to get the encrypted text.

Right now I'm getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for using GCP and Cloud KMS! What are you putting into "API KEY" in your example?

Comment: I'm using the curl command specified here: https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt#kms-howto-encrypt-protocol         

Command with API:
curl -s -X POST "https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/global/keyRings/test/cryptoKeys/quickstart:encrypt" \
  -d "{\"plaintext\":\"[BASE64_ENCODED_INPUT]\"}" \
  -H "Authorization:Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXX"\
  -H "Content-Type:application/json"

Comment: Where did you get the authorization token in this function ("AIzaSy ... Ew")? What identity do you want people to use when encrypting/decrypting? As themselves (their personal accounts would be on the ACL for the key)? If so, you would use the flows described on https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user to get an API KEY.

Comment: I created the token on the "API's and services" page. Create credentials -> API-key... I don't know which identity they should have? I just want them to be able te encrypt/decrypt scripted with the use of the API KEY.

Comment: The token should start with `ya29.`. I think you may be using the wrong type of API token. As Tim mentioned, you should follow the steps on this page to get a token: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user

Comment: I looked into the documentation you both provided. But somehow I'm not able to create an API key that starts with ya29. I can only create API keys, when you're both talking about API tokens? I found the following documentation: https://medium.com/@pablo127/google-api-authentication-with-oauth-2-on-the-example-of-gmail-a103c897fd98. 
They received an acces token starting with ya29 like the one I should use. But I need an way to request this token with only the API KEY and without confirming Oauth 2.

Comment: @sethvargo Thanks for your response. Is it even possible to encrypt plaintext with only an API_KEY, without Oauth2? I created an API_KEY and restricted the the to "Cloud Key Management Service (KMS) API" but I still can't get it working.

Comment: I do not believe it's possible to call GCP APIs without an oauth token.